# Delphi 10.4 compiler error: "Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical"

Tags: delphi, winapi, compiler-errors, delphi-10.4-sydney

I'm new to programming. I'm using Delphi 10.4 Community Edition. I'm trying to run the BassPlayer demo project, but I get an error when trying to compile and run it. It happens in a file named `wa_ipc.pas` on line 1691. I have no idea how to fix this error.

```
function SendMessageRetStr(wnd: HWND; uMsg: UINT; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): String;
var
  dwProcessId: DWORD;
  phandle: THandle;
  P: Pointer;
  C: Cardinal;
  PB: Pointer;
  B: Byte;
begin
  Result := '';
  GetWindowThreadProcessID(wnd, pointer(dwProcessId));
  phandle := OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, False, dwProcessId);
  if phandle = 0 then exit;
  P := Pointer(SendMessage(wnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam));
  PB := nil;
  B := 0;
  repeat
    if not ReadProcessMemory(phandle,P,@PB,1,C) then break; (*<-- Error message here*)
    B := Byte(PB);
    if B <> 0 then begin
      Result := Result + Chr(B);
    end;
    P := Pointer(DWord(P)+1);
  until (B=0);

  CloseHandle(phandle);
end;
```

The error I get is:

> [dcc32 Error] wa_ipc.pas(1691): E2033 Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical

Within the `Winapi.Windows.pas` unit, the `ReadProcessMemory()` function is declared as:

```
function ReadProcessMemory(hProcess: THandle; const lpBaseAddress: Pointer; lpBuffer: Pointer; nSize: SIZE_T; var lpNumberOfBytesRead: SIZE_T): BOOL; stdcall;
```

Comment: We don't know what the compiler error is, we don't know how you are compiling this code, and you claim to be using two different versions of Delphi

Comment: Sorry. I edited the post and added the error message.

Answer (score 1):

I see a number of problems with this code.

- Your use of `pointer(dwProcessId)` in the 2nd parameter of `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` is wrong. It *will not* work as expected at runtime. You are passing an invalid memory address for the API to write to, leading to *undefined behavior*. You need to use `@dwProcessId` instead.
- Your use of `@PB` in the 3rd parameter of `ReadProcessMemory()` is wrong. You are reading 1 byte from the remote process into a `Pointer` variable, and then you are truncating that `Pointer` into a `Byte`. Although this *will* behave as expected at runtime, it is *logically* wrong, you really should use `@B` instead and get rid of `PB` altogether.
- Your use of `C` in the 5th parameter of `ReadProcessMemory()` is wrong. This is the cause of your compiler error. In the Win32 API, that parameter expects a *pointer* to a `SIZE_T` (which is a pointer-sized unsigned integer), not the *value* of a `Cardinal` (which is a fixed-sized 32bit unsigned integer).  In Delphi's `Winapi.Windows` unit, that parameter is declared as a `var` reference to a `SIZE_T` variable, not a `var` reference to a `Cardinal` variable, hence why you are getting the compiler error. You must  declare your variable the exact same data type that the `var` reference is expecting.
- The remote data in question is clearly an 8bit null-terminated ANSI string, but you are appending the 8bit characters as-is to a 16bit `UnicodeString`. Unless the characters in question are purely ASCII, the result will not be what you are expecting.
- You are casting your `P` pointer to a `Dword` when incrementing its value. `Dword` is a 32bit integer, so that cast will only work correctly if your app is compiled as a 32bit executable, which uses 32bit memory addresses at runtime. But in a 64bit executable, you risk truncating the memory address that the pointer is pointing at. You would need to use `DWORD_PTR` (or equivalent) instead.

Now, with all of that said, try something more like this instead:

```
function SendMessageRetStr(wnd: HWND; uMsg: UINT; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): String;
var
  dwProcessId: DWORD;
  hProcess: THandle;
  PCh: LRESULT;
  bytesRead: SIZE_T;
  Ch: AnsiChar;
  S: AnsiString;
begin
  Result := '';
  GetWindowThreadProcessID(wnd, @dwProcessId);
  hProcess := OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, False, dwProcessId);
  if hProcess = 0 then Exit;
  try
    PCh := SendMessage(wnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    repeat
      if not ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, Pointer(PCh), @Ch, 1, bytesRead{or: PSize_t(nil)^}) then break;
      if Ch = #0 then break;
      S := S + Ch;
      Inc(PCh);
    until False;
  finally
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
  end;
  Result := string(S);
end;
```

Comment: I tried your modified code but it gave me the same error. I edited the post and added more info. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: See the update to my answer that I made yesterday

Comment: This is a really good answer. Weird how some answers do not get any upvotes...